# Issue with Minipupper ROS1 - Spawning Multiple Instances in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-noetic, ekf-localization, namespaces

I am currently working with Minipupper in ROS1 and I'm facing an issue while trying to spawn two instances of it in Gazebo. To achieve this, I am using a parameter in the gazebo.launch file called "robot_name," which makes use of namespaces for each robot instance. Here's how I start the launch file:

```
roslaunch mini_pupper_gazebo gazebo.launch robot_name:=robot1
```

I've observed that in the minipupper_bringup/champ_bringup.launch file, two ekf_localization nodes are launched(base_to_footprint_ekf and footprint_to_odom_ekf). When I comment out these lines everything works, but when it's not commented, things don't work and the following error appears:

```
Could not obtain transform from base_link to robot1/base_footprint. Error was "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.
```

I've checked the tf_tree, and it seems to be configured correctly with the appropriate node and tf_prefix namespaces.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into why the ekf_localization nodes might be causing this problem, I would greatly appreciate your help.

[image: rqt graph]

[image: tf tree graph]

## Log output

```
adamzr@ASUS-TUF-Gaming:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch mini_pupper_gazebo gazebo.launch robot_name:=robot1
... logging to /home/adamzr/.ros/log/17170bae-74d6-11ee-94c0-99e7e9fa2aed/roslaunch-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-20153.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://127.0.0.1:46155/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/base_link_frame: base_link
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/frequency: 50
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/imu0: imu/data
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/imu0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/odom_frame: base_footprint
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/pose0: base_to_footprint...
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/pose0_config: [True, True, True...
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/transform_time_offset: 0.045
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/transform_timeout: 0.01
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/two_d_mode: False
 * /robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf/world_frame: base_footprint
 * /robot1/champ_controller/gazebo: True
 * /robot1/champ_controller/joint_controller_topic: joint_group_posit...
 * /robot1/champ_controller/publish_foot_contacts: False
 * /robot1/champ_controller/publish_joint_control: True
 * /robot1/champ_controller/publish_joint_states: True
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/base_link_frame: base_footprint
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/frequency: 50
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/imu0: imu/data
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/imu0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/odom0: odom/raw
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/odom0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/odom_frame: odom
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/transform_timeout: 0.01
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/two_d_mode: True
 * /robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf/world_frame: odom
 * /robot1/gait/com_x_translation: 0.0
 * /robot1/gait/knee_orientation: >>
 * /robot1/gait/max_angular_velocity_z: 1.0
 * /robot1/gait/max_linear_velocity_x: 0.15
 * /robot1/gait/max_linear_velocity_y: 0.15
 * /robot1/gait/nominal_height: 0.06
 * /robot1/gait/odom_scaler: 1.0
 * /robot1/gait/pantograph_leg: False
 * /robot1/gait/stance_depth: 0.0
 * /robot1/gait/stance_duration: 0.2
 * /robot1/gait/swing_height: 0.012
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lb1/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lb1/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lb1/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lf1/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lf1/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_lf1/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rb1/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rb1/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rb1/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rf1/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rf1/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/base_rf1/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb1_lb2/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb1_lb2/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb1_lb2/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb2_lb3/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb2_lb3/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lb2_lb3/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf1_lf2/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf1_lf2/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf1_lf2/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf2_lf3/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf2_lf3/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/lf2_lf3/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb1_rb2/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb1_rb2/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb1_rb2/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb2_rb3/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb2_rb3/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rb2_rb3/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf1_rf2/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf1_rf2/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf1_rf2/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf2_rf3/d: 0.005
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf2_rf3/i: 2.5
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/gains/rf2_rf3/p: 15
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/joints: ['base_lf1', 'lf1...
 * /robot1/joint_group_position_controller/type: effort_controller...
 * /robot1/joint_states_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /robot1/joint_states_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /robot1/joints_map/left_front: ['base_lf1', 'lf1...
 * /robot1/joints_map/left_hind: ['base_lb1', 'lb1...
 * /robot1/joints_map/right_front: ['base_rf1', 'rf1...
 * /robot1/joints_map/right_hind: ['base_rb1', 'rb1...
 * /robot1/links_map/base: base_link
 * /robot1/links_map/left_front: ['lf1', 'lf2', 'l...
 * /robot1/links_map/left_hind: ['lb1', 'lb2', 'l...
 * /robot1/links_map/right_front: ['rf1', 'rf2', 'r...
 * /robot1/links_map/right_hind: ['rb1', 'rb2', 'r...
 * /robot1/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot1/robot_state_publisher/ignore_timestamp: True
 * /robot1/robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 200
 * /robot1/robot_state_publisher/use_tf_static: False
 * /robot1/state_estimator/orientation_from_imu: True
 * /robot1/tf_prefix: robot1
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/accel_lim_v: 1.0
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/accel_lim_w: 2.0
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/decel_factor: 1.0
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/frequency: 10.0
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/quiet: True
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/robot_feedback: 2
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/speed_lim_v_x: 0.5
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/speed_lim_v_y: 0.35
 * /robot1/velocity_smoother/speed_lim_w: 0.4
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
  /robot1/
    base_to_footprint_ekf (robot_localization/ekf_localization_node)
    champ_controller (champ_base/quadruped_controller_node)
    contact_sensor (champ_gazebo/contact_sensor)
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    footprint_to_odom_ekf (robot_localization/ekf_localization_node)
    nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    state_estimator (champ_base/state_estimation_node)
    urdf_spawner (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    velocity_smoother (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [20161]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311

setting /run_id to 17170bae-74d6-11ee-94c0-99e7e9fa2aed
WARNING: Package name "aliengoZ1_description" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [20171]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot1/robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [20178]
process[robot1/nodelet_manager-3]: started with pid [20179]
process[robot1/velocity_smoother-4]: started with pid [20180]
process[robot1/champ_controller-5]: started with pid [20181]
process[robot1/state_estimator-6]: started with pid [20182]
process[robot1/base_to_footprint_ekf-7]: started with pid [20187]
[ WARN] [1698417335.967184938]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
process[robot1/footprint_to_odom_ekf-8]: started with pid [20193]
process[gazebo-9]: started with pid [20198]
process[gazebo_gui-10]: started with pid [20204]
process[robot1/urdf_spawner-11]: started with pid [20216]
process[robot1/controller_spawner-12]: started with pid [20221]
process[robot1/contact_sensor-13]: started with pid [20222]
[ INFO] [1698417336.018243057]: Successfully parsed urdf file
WARNING: Package name "aliengoZ1_description" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
WARNING: Package name "aliengoZ1_description" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
[ INFO] [1698417336.046166055]: Successfully parsed urdf file
[ WARN] [1698417336.085858087]: Warning: Some linear velocity entries in parameter imu0_config are listed true, but an sensor_msgs/Imu contains no information about linear velocities
[ WARN] [1698417336.088396121]: Warning: imu/data is listed as an input topic, but all its update variables are false
WARNING: Package name "aliengoZ1_description" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
WARNING: Package name "aliengoZ1_description" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
[INFO] [1698417336.319811, 0.000000]: Waiting for /clock to be available...
[ INFO] [1698417336.487085061]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1698417336.488040681]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1698417336.577297496]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1698417336.578111977]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1698417336.920205593]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1698417336.969722357]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ INFO] [1698417337.511710374, 0.001000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: 'robot1'
[ INFO] [1698417337.511758944, 0.001000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = robot1)
[ INFO] [1698417337.512621051, 0.001000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = robot1)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "robot1"
[ INFO] [1698417337.828273741, 0.001000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: 'robot1'
[ INFO] [1698417337.830531117, 0.001000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = robot1)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "robot1"
[ WARN] [1698417337.830547199, 0.001000000]: dynamic reconfigure is not enabled for this image topic [/camera/color/image_raw] becuase <cameraName> is not specified
[ INFO] [1698417337.874760870, 0.001000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1698417337.874908759, 0.001000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: robot1
[ INFO] [1698417337.875360483, 0.001000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot1/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ INFO] [1698417337.996148577, 0.001000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[robot1/urdf_spawner-11] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/adamzr/.ros/log/17170bae-74d6-11ee-94c0-99e7e9fa2aed/robot1-urdf_spawner-11*.log
[INFO] [1698417338.443758, 0.201000]: /clock is published. Proceeding to load the controller(s).
[INFO] [1698417338.444657, 0.201000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.446289, 0.202000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.448489, 0.202000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.450760, 0.203000]: Loading controller: joint_states_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.459251, 0.207000]: Loading controller: joint_group_position_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.621371, 0.276000]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_states_controller, joint_group_position_controller
[INFO] [1698417338.625170, 0.277000]: Started controllers: joint_states_controller, joint_group_position_controller
[ WARN] [1698417343.208233972, 2.000000000]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to robot1/base_footprint. Error was "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 

[ WARN] [1698417348.348611930, 4.000000000]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to robot1/base_footprint. Error was "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 

[ WARN] [1698417353.543821117, 6.000000000]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to robot1/base_footprint. Error was "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.
```